# Using YouTube for e-learning

Tags: html, youtube

I have a HTML page with 30 links each pointing to a YouTube video. All videos belong to the same YouTube Channel.
The HTML page also features a YouTube player.
I am trying to figure out if the following is possible (possibly without using PHP): Once a link is clicked, the video player refreshes on the same page and showes the video. The page itself does not refresh - only the video player does.
Are there any options other than PHP?
Can anyone link me to some sort of super easy guide for doing it myself? (..."below beginner" level).

Answer (score 1):

How you are linking with youtube? with `iframe` tag ? If you are using `iframe` then you can see all the videos in same page only. Page won't refresh.

If it is not the case please be more specific.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using jquery. In the href attribute of links, use video's embedded url, as in below code.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {      
        $('a').click(function() {
            $('iframe').attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
            return false;
        });
    })
</script>

<iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J5x5gduEWtI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br><br>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/J5x5gduEWtI'>Link1</a>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WmDmUDXxeXU'>Link2</a>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/UNlgAuMWuvw'>Link3</a>
```

**Edit:**
This will also works.

```
<iframe id='iframe' width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/J5x5gduEWtI" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<br><br>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/J5x5gduEWtI' target='iframe'>Link1</a>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/WmDmUDXxeXU' target='iframe'>Link2</a>
<a href='http://www.youtube.com/embed/UNlgAuMWuvw' target='iframe'>Link3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the page to refresh, then your only option is JavaScript (i.e. you have to do it clientside).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by keep the youtube player in an iframe which has some ID (e.g: id="playerFrame"). Then in the relevant hyper link ('a' tag), put the id of the iframe as the value of "target" attribute.

```
<iframe id="playerFrame"></iframe>
<a href="http://youtubeurl" target="playerFrame">Click to see video 1</a>
```

See http://webdesign.about.com/od/iframes/qt/target-links-iframes-and-frames.htm